# Simple if statement inside a for looping

Tags: r, if-statement

I have never work with if statement and I have to produce a simple one.

```
value=c(250,200,180)

vector1<-c(1:10)
vector2<-c(11:20)
vector3<-c(21:30)

matrixmy<-cbind(vector1,vector2,vector3)
```

My if statement will be inside a function, (`myfunction`). The idea is:

- when `function(250)` I will use the first column of matrix `matrixmy[,1]` for the rest of the function.
- when `function(220)` I will use the second column of matrix `matrixmy[,2]` for the rest of the function.
- when `function(200)` I will use the first column of matrix `matrixmy[,3]` for the rest of the function

The function is already implemented, but I couldn't do a reproducible example.

The idea I've been thinking for the if else statement is:

```
if value[i]=250 then j=1
       sample=matrixmy[,1] 

          else 

if value[i]=220 then
       sample=matrixmy[,2] 

          else
then value[i]=200 then j=3

       sample=matrixmy[,3]
```

Is it clear?

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: I strongly suggest you study some R tutorials and learn the proper syntax for the `if` control-flow construct in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify things alot, just use:

```
index <- c(`250` = 1, `220` = 2, `200` = 3)[as.character(value[i])]
sample = matrixmy[, index]
```

---

If you want to stick to your code, use something like this.

```
if (value[i]==250) j=1
if (value[i]==220) j=2
if (value[i]==200) j=3

sample=matrixmy[,j]
```